# Is 1500 the limit on concurrent QLDB transactions?

Tags: amazon-qldb

Based on this answer : [Amazon QLDB have any scaling/performance limits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58254582/amazon-qldb-have-any-scaling-performance-limits)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

A QLDB session can have 1 active transaction. And, a ledger (not account!) can have up to 1500 sessions. This limit can be raised by filing for a limit increase.

I gave additional info in my [answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58254582/amazon-qldb-have-any-scaling-performance-limits/58630222?noredirect=1#comment105595885_58630222) on the other thread.